# Cannot fully utilise all cpu using multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool Module

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have a 32 core machine , using multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool library to generate ThreadPool of Size 32. I have given the sample snippet in my case 2 D Array is huge.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
import time

def f(x):
    return x[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(32)              # start 4 worker processes

    startTime=time.time()
    twoDimensionalArraay=[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]

    d=pool.map(f,twoDimensionalArraay)


    print time.time()-startTime
```

After running the process i ran the top command . and saw that out of 32 only one core is busy rest are IDLE

```
Cpu(s):  2.3%us,  1.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 96.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  132158392k total, 98751480k used, 33406912k free,   230528k buffers
Swap:  2097148k total,        0k used,  2097148k free, 17625092k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                        
 8062 centos    20   0 80.7g  75g  10m S 194.1 59.8  34:49.95 python
```

Can anyone tell me how to fully utilise this cpu so that all the processors are busy

Comment: `os.system("taskset -p 0xFFFFFFFF %d" % os.getpid())`

Comment: You say "after running the process", try seeing how many are in use _while_ running the process.

Comment: sorry its while running process

Comment: OK, in that case you should [edit] your question and correct it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the issue is because you're using `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` as the `Pool`, not `multiprocessing.Pool`. The former creates thread-based dummy Process objects that wrap a Python thread, so using it doesn't create separate processes like the latter does.

Try using `from multiprocessing import Pool` instead.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: You were very right on this, it worked perfectly on all my 20 cores

Comment: I already upvoted it, i'm not the one who asked the question.

Comment: @CodeGuru: Sorry, I was confused about the source of the comment.